# How to upload a different image for a resolution?

Tags: html, css

I have this sample:

[link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gwxPOj)

**CODE HTML:**

```
<img src="http://www.exn.ro/poze/pozeexn/412.jpg" srcset="http://www.pozewallpaper.com/images/Wallpapere/Peisaje/poze_peisaje_24.jpg 1000w, http://www.zgubilitic.ro/img/mar12/peisaje-superbe-24.jpg 2000w" >
```

Basically what I want to upload a different picture for different resolutions.

I made a simple scheme below to understand more clearly what they want

```
if(large resolution)
{
   loag pic1.jpg
}elseif(medium resolution)
{
   load pic2.jpg
}elseif (small resolution)
{
   load pic3.jpg
}
```

I wish something like ... as in the above scheme ..
you think you can do that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Too broad; go research “responsive images” or similar.

Comment: CSS media queries. Google it! ;)

Comment: @Goombah — No! This is for content images.

Comment: search for `src-set` you will get better than your code

Comment: "Basically what I want to upload a different picture for different resolutions" — You already have that. That's the whole point of the `srcset` attribute (which you have already given different values for different solutions) in the code you shared.

Answer (score 0):

There is some expirmental pieces of HTML code that are being considered by the W3C. One of these is `<picture>` which allows for media queries to be used to determine which image is used.

```html
<picture>
    <source srcset="image-large.png" media="(min-width: 1000px)">
    <source srcset="image-medium.png" media="(min-width: 800px)">
    <img src="image-small.png" alt="image">
</picture>
```

The browser support for this is sketchy but seems to be along the lines of what you would like to do. This may not work right now but is being considered for the future and I'm sure many website's will make use of this cool piece of code once/if it becomes available

- [MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture)
- [W3C Documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/2013/WD-html-picture-element-20130226/#the-picture-element)

Comment: You can use `srcset` on the `<img>` directly to … and the code in the question is already doing that. It really isn't clear what the problem is.

Comment: MDNs [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img) doesn't seem to make any suggestion that srcset is at all related to the font size.

Comment: Apologies, misread it. Either way, the answer provided is a possible solution so I don't see what the problem is.